# Python, sort with key

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-re

I am having trouble understanding `key` parameter in `sorted` function in Python.
Let us say, the following list is given: `sample_list = ['Date ', 'of', 'birth', 'year 1990', 'month 10', 'day 15']` and I would like to sort only the strings that contain number.

Expected output: `['Date ', 'of', 'birth', 'month 10', 'day 15', 'year 1990']`

Until now, I only managed to print the string with the number

```
def sort_with_key(element_of_list):
    if re.search('\d+', element_of_list):
        print(element_of_list)
    return element_of_list
```

`sorted(sample_list, key = sort_with_key)`

But how do I actually sort those elements?
Thank you!

Comment: It's quite unclear what you want to achieve. The function you pass as `key` is applied to every element, i.e. you cannot sort only some elements by using key. You can however sort part of the list and create new one combining unsorted (first 3 elements) and sorted (the remaining elements). That said - how exactly you "sort" the day, month and the year, i.e. I don't think you really mean "sort", but order month, day, year. Also - how did you get this list in the first place?

Comment: @buran there is an answer, thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try sorting with a lambda:

```py
sample_list = ['Date ', 'of', 'birth', 'year 1990', 'month 10', 'day 15']
sample_list = sorted(sample_list, key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[0]) if re.search(r'\d+', x) else 0)
print(sample_list)
```

This prints:

```
['Date ', 'of', 'birth', 'month 10', 'day 15', 'year 1990']
```

The logic used in the lambda is to sort by the number in each list entry, if the entry has a number.  Otherwise, it assigns a value of zero to other entries, placing them first in the sort.

Comment: what if day is 02 and month is 12? I don't really think OP would expect day to come before month

Comment: @buran I wanted to sort only by number, day/month/year are irrelevant. Sorry for confusion

Comment: @buran I agree that the premise may not seem to make sense.  But maybe the sample data given is just anecdotal and the general problem is just to sort by the integer value in each list entry.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want strings with a number to be sorted with this number as key, and strings without a number to be at the beginning?

You need a key that extracts the number from the string. We can use `str.isdigit()` to extract digits from a string, `''.join()` to put these digits back together, and `int()` to convert to an integer. If there are no digits in the string, we'll return `-1` instead, so it comes before all nonnegative numbers.

```py
sample_list = ['Date ', 'of', 'birth', 'year 1990', 'month 10', 'day 15', 'answer 42', 'small number 0', 'large number 8676965', 'no number here']

sample_list.sort(key=lambda s: int(''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit()) or -1))

print(sample_list)
# ['Date ', 'of', 'birth', 'no number here', 'small number 0', 'month 10', 'day 15', 'answer 42', 'year 1990', 'large number 8676965']
```